# How do I send an automated link, in chat, to invite the asker to join me in a chat room for further discussion?

Tags: support, comments, chat, comment-replies

I am prominent on a particular exchange where one user has taken it up on themself to post regular posts trying to pick at basic rules on how Stack Exchange works. I have pointed out that it is a Meta Stack Exchange issue, but they insist that thay have to ask it in the per-site Meta, as they do not have enough reputation to ask, here.

I am previously use to having an option to simply invite the user to discuss in a private chatroom away from the meta post, as it is clear his misunderstanding of how Stack Exchange works goes past a couple of comments or more. But I can not find the option.

How do I send an automated link, in chat, to invite the asker to join me in a chat room for further discussion?

Comment: Everyone can ask or answer questions here. There is no 5 rep limit as there is on per-site metas.

Comment: The method described in the dupe's answer cause instant inbox notification for the one being invited. (It's not mentioned in the answer)